# how to get the top 10 selling products and the lowest 3 selling stores of each

Tags: sql, t-sql

i am trying to build a query from 3 tables. sales, stores and items.
the goal is to get the top 10 selling products and for each to show the stores with the lowest sales.
i have the following query but it doesn't get the top distinct products as it refers to the store_desc as well. the goal is to get the top 10 products with most sales without the store desc and then to get the lowest "a" which is quantity

```
select distinct top 10 sum(net_sale) as sales, sum(quantity) 
as a,  sales.item_code,stores.store_desc from sales  join 
stores on stores.store_code=sales.store_code group by 
sales.net_sale, sales.item_code,stores.store_desc  order by 
sales desc
```

Comment: sample data and expected output is helpful

Comment: I am making the assumption you want only the worst store, or one of the worst stores if many are equally bad. I would use a "select top 1" subquery for the store part instead of a simple join. then you can have 2 "order by". one in the main query and one in the subquery

Answer (score 1):

You get the sales for each product per store using:

```
select s.store_code, s.item_code, sum(i.quantity) as qty
from sales s
group by s.store_code, s.item_code;
```

With one addition, we get the total quantity per store as well:

```
select s.store_code, s.item_code, sum(i.quantity) as qty,
       sum(sum(i.quantity)) over (partition by s.item_code) as item_qty
from sales s
group by s.store_code, s.item_code;
```

Then, with this as a subquery, we can enumerate them:

```
select s.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by item_qty desc) as item_rank,
       row_number() over (partition by item_code order by qty asc) as item_store_rank
from (select s.store_code, s.item_code, sum(i.quantity) as qty,
             sum(sum(i.quantity)) over (partition by s.item_code) as item_qty
      from sales s
      group by s.store_code, s.item_code
     ) s
```

Then make this a subquery.  You want:

```
where item_rank <= 10 and item_store_rank <= 3
```

Note:  This does not account for stores that do not sell certain items.  If that is an issue, I would recommend that you ask a *new* question with clarification on how to handle such cases.